# SSRS/T-SQL sum if another condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Basically I have an application that processes transactions. Each transaction has a transaction number. In the application view on the front the total for each transaction is calculated but it is not stored in the database (and this cannot be changed)

Now in SSRS they want to see the value come through on the report. The way to do this is to match the transaction number and if they match (no matter how many records) it adds them up on is there a way to do this on SSRS? Or maybe a more elegant way to do it would be to do it in the stored procedure.

And example of this is below which I know won't work but just to give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish here:

```
SELECT  transactionID
        , value
        , Sum(Case When transactionID = TransactionID Then Value Else 0) As Total
```

EDIT: In response to some of the comments I made this edit. First off in the above I made a mistake and did TransactionID = transaction but it should be what it is currently.

Continuing on... In order to do this I need to match the transaction number against other transaction numbers in the data set and see if there is a match. To illustrate I did this example below:

This is an example dataset:

- TransId: 1 Value: 200
- TransId: 2 Value: 300
- TransId: 1 Value: 100
- TransId: 2 Value: 500
- TransId: 1 Value: 400

From this dataset I should get these values in the report:

- TransId: 1 Value: 200 Total: 700
- TransId: 2 Value: 300 Total: 800
- TransId: 1 Value: 100 Total: 700
- TransId: 2 Value: 500 Total: 800
- TransId: 1 Value: 400 Total: 700

So for each row I want to see the complete total for each record(TransID) and not a runnign total.

Comment: *The way to do this is to match the transaction number*, match it against what?

Comment: I fail to see why what you posted won't work? Is Transaction something internal to the report? stored in a table somewhere? We need more details about this.

Comment: Do you want the total of the transaction added to each transaction record of the report? I.E.  TranId1, Value 2.2, Total 8.0 <br> TranId1, Value 5.8, Total 8.0?  If so just make a total CTE using tranid, sum(value) group by tranid and join it to the transaction table using the id.

Comment: Or do you want to create a "running total" report using the values?

Comment: I answered all of your questions above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Window functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) are just so much more fun though:

```
SELECT TransactionId
    , Value
    , SUM(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY TransactionId) AS Total
FROM SomeTable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/667dca/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
select transactionID
     , value
     , TransactionSum
 from MyTable t
  join (select transactionID 
             , sum (value) as TransactionSum 
          from MyTable
         group by transactionID
       ) x on t.transactionID = x.transactionID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing it

```
select a.transid,
       a.value,
       (select sum(b.value) from yourTable b where b.transid = a.transid) as Total
from yourTable a
```